# Can redis-server executable can be used with .conf file as well as -- cmd line option?

Tags: redis, startup, redis-server

I have an requirement to pass a default .conf file to redis-server executable while starting redis and at the same time i want to override some config param while runnng redis-server executable without touching .conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the [configuration](https://redis.io/topics/config) as an argument to the process and then override each one of the properties with `--` flag arg.

e.g.

```
redis-server myredis.conf --requirepass "hello world"
```